# How can i export data from my express router

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have some route, and it works and render me result

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    const data = bigCommerce.verify(req.query['signed_payload']);
    res.render('load', { title: 'Welcome!', data: JSON.stringify(data, ['store_hash'])}); 
});

module.exports = router;
```

But i need get result `JSON.stringify(data, ['store_hash'])` and export him to the other file like some constant.

How can i do it?

Comment: can you explain more about what's the other file ?

Comment: @asela-priyadarshana some config file, like .env